# Multiple forms in single php file

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am currently working on a PHP CMS and am trying to create a edit page for a news system.

when the user goes to the edit page and a article has not been selected yet, they should get a form to select an article to edit.

When the user selects an article to edit, the page should (refresh?) display a form with the selected articles content to be edited.

---

all of my pages are included within my index.php based on p=pagename being set.

When I go to the edit news page I see http://puu.sh/fhYO7/569146d037.png (which is correct).

When I select a news article to edit it sends me to http://puu.sh/fhZ13/2ca0f7d974.png with the url as: mysite.com/admin/editnews.php?id=4

if I manually enter what the URL should be: mysite.com/admin/index.php?p=editnews&id=4 i get this - http://puu.sh/fhZ6h/d38e97d0bb.png

**My current code:** editnews.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    include_once('includes/connection.php');
    include_once('includes/news.php');

    $news = new AdminNews;

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        $newss = $news->fetch_all();

        if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $content = br2nl($_POST['content']);

            if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
                $error = 'All fields are required!';
                header('Location: index.php?p=editnews');
            } else {
                global $pdo;

                $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE admin_news SET news_title = ?, news_content = ? WHERE news_id=?');
                $query->bindValue(1, $title);
                $query->bindValue(2, $content);
                $query->bindValue(3, $id);

                $query->execute();

                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
    ?>
    <!-- POST -->
    <div class="post">
        <div class="topwrap">
            <div class="userinfo pull-left">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="status green">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>

                <div class="icons">
                    <img src="images/icon1.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon4.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon5.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon6.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="posttext pull-left">
                <h2>Edit News</h2>
                <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
                    <small><?php echo $error; ?></small>
                <?php } ?>
                <!-- add news form start !-->
                <form action="editnews.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $news['news_title'] ?> /><br /><br />
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="87" value="<?php echo $news['news_content'] ?>" name="content" /></textarea>
                    <!-- add news form break !-->
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>                              
        <div class="postinfobot">

            <div class="dateposted pull-right">
                    <!-- add news form continue !-->
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
                </form>
                <!-- add news form end !-->
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- POST -->
    <?php
        } else {
    ?>
    <!-- POST -->
    <div class="post">
        <div class="topwrap">
            <div class="userinfo pull-left">

            </div>
            <div class="posttext pull-left">
                <h2>Select a News Post to Delete</h2>
                <!-- form start !-->
                <form action="editnews.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                    <select name="id">
                        <?php foreach ($newss as $news) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $news['news_id']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $news['news_title']; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    <!-- form break !-->
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>                              
        <div class="postinfobot">
            <div class="dateposted pull-right">
                <!-- form continue !-->
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Edit News" />
                </form>
                <!-- form end !-->
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- POST -->
    <?php
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    ?>
```

I am completely lost on this one (just started getting back into PHP after 10+ years away from it).

**The Question is:**
what am I doing wrong, why isnt it sending me to the correct url, why is it displaying strange when I enter what the URL should be?

Comment: so, what's your exact question?

Comment: what am I doing wrong, why isnt it sending me to the correct url, why is it displaying strange when I enter what the URL should be? I have been toying with this for hours and havent been able to resolve anything that is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices: 
1. Get the form to post to index.php instead of editnews.php and take care of the data in index.php. In other words change:

```
<form action="editnews.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

to:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

2. Submit the form with ajax without page refresh. This means you have to handle the button click in javascript and process the form with an ajax-call to url editnews.php

In jquery this can be done like so:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    $.post('editnews.php', 
    {
        title: $('#name').val(), 
        content: $('#content').val()
    }, 
    function(data) {
        console.log(data); //response
        $('#name, #content').val(''); /* Clear the inputs */
    }, 
    'text');
    return false; //Stop form from refreshing page
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try wrting with a slash at the beginning:

```
header('Location: /index.php?p=editnews');
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**I finally figured out a solution (it only took FOREVER)...**

*First* what I did is removed the news select form and just turned the selection into a list of linked titles that would take you to the proper link with &id=#.

*Then* I changed the check to see if the id was set or not, if so display the form to edit (form was displaying wrong because there was a missing " and ; in my form.

**Fixed Code:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/news.php');
include_once('includes/functions.php');

$news = new AdminNews;
$funct = new UserFunctions;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $newss = $news->fetch_all();

    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

        if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
            header('Location: index.php?p=editnews');
        } else {
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE admin_news SET news_title = ?, news_content = ? WHERE news_id=?');
            $query->bindValue(1, $title);
            $query->bindValue(2, $content);
            $query->bindValue(3, $id);

            $query->execute();

            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin_news WHERE news_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();

        $rows = $query->fetchAll();

        //set username to variable
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $id = $row['news_id'];
            $title = $row['news_title'];
            $content = $funct->br2nl($row['news_content']);
        }
?>
<!-- POST -->
<div class="post">
    <div class="topwrap">
        <div class="userinfo pull-left">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="status green">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>

            <div class="icons">
                <img src="images/icon1.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon4.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon5.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon6.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="posttext pull-left">
            <h2>Edit News</h2>
            <!-- add news form start !-->
            <form action="editnews.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br /><br />
                <textarea rows="10" cols="87" name="content" /><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
                <!-- add news form break !-->
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>                              
    <div class="postinfobot">

        <div class="dateposted pull-right">
                <!-- add news form continue !-->
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
            </form>
            <!-- add news form end !-->
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- POST -->
<?php
    } else {
?>
<!-- POST -->
<div class="post">
    <div class="topwrap">
        <div class="userinfo pull-left">

        </div>
        <div class="posttext pull-left">
            <h2>Select a News Post to Delete</h2>
                    <?php foreach ($newss as $news) { ?>
                        <?php echo $news['news_id']; ?> - <a href="index.php?p=editnews&id=<?php echo $news['news_id']; ?>"><?php echo $news['news_title']; ?></a><br /><br />
                    <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>                              
    <div class="postinfobot">
        <div class="dateposted pull-right"> </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- POST -->
<?php
    }
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```